# App Project - Displaying Data

Tags: web-app, mobile-application

[image]

Please see attached. I need to represent this data within an App. My thoughts are just to keep it as a list - with pretty icons. The user will be doing nothing with this data, it is just for reference. I did consider putting this info into boxes, but the boxes may look clickable and also will take up more room, making the page even longer than what it already is!

What do we think?

Comment: I think we need some more background to help you sort through this one. What is this app for? Who are your users? What are their goals?

Comment: I agree with Andrew Martin, is this simple help so people can understand the format of the data? Rather than have it as a lengthy list, why not make it in-line help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the data is but could you only show the most important things to users? so you don't have longer page and keep it simple?

You also could split the list by category and make them collapse.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Keep it simple and display data similar to http://nutritiondata.self.com.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting ****Sorting
Sort your data by priority and sort those data again.
Go through your users and use cases .
Ask yourself a question why are you showing all the data.
Show only what is required.
In mobile cases use tables or sort data by making a super categories.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your user, but to start, I would begin by sorting the data by both order of importance (important values first) and categories. So separate the data by category to make it less visually intimidating and show important values first so users don't need to search for them.